# Invert unsigned arbitrary binary bits in javascript

Tags: javascript

For instance, 10100 would be inverted to 01011; 010 would be inverted to 101; 101 would be converted to 010.

The problem is when I use ~5, it becomes -6 because js uses 32 bit signed.

How do I invert an unsigned arbitrary-bit binary number?

I would like to create a function that takes in this unsigned arbitrary-bit binary number and return its inverted form( 101->010)

I want to convert from string 101 to 010

Comment: 010 -> 101 ... how would you determine that you should only flip 3 bits? why not 5 bits like in 10100 -> 01011?

Comment: I can't use ~5u because I want to pass in a number say 101 and use this function to return 010

Comment: you are passing in strings? like '010',  that can work

Comment: 010->101 is an example. I have stated it arbitrary bits meaning any number bits

Comment: yes, but I'm asking how do you determine the number of bits to flip ... 010 == 0000000010 ... but 101 !== 1111111101

Comment: @JaromandaX it doesn't work, java script generates a negative number using ~

Comment: what doesn't work? I'm asking **you** how you determine the number of bits to flip ... why would 010 only flip 3 bits? as a Number, 010 is 2 ... but that's 0000000000000010 in 32 bit ...

Comment: @JaromandaX after the flip, 010 should be 101; that is to say it should cut off any bits left of 101

Comment: why? what determines that? 010 in binary is also 10 ... and 00000010 ... why 3 digits, not 2, or 5?

Comment: are you working with STRINGS "010" etc ...

Comment: @JaromandaX, I'm not sure what you mean by what determines that. All I want is when I pass in say 1111, it generates 0000 in the console but not 0.

Comment: @JaromandaX yes strings

Comment: @ZacUwyoH My answer should solve it for you, I understand what you mean about the significant bits in the input number, in the same way 523 has 3 significant unsigned bits, 101 has 3 significant unsigned bits.

Comment: This will produce some strange results, e.g. 3 is 11, flipping just the significant bits gives 00 (i.e. 0). Is that the desired result?

Comment: oh ... strings ... let me edit the answer then

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create a function that flips the required number of digits like so

```js
    var flipbits = function (v, digits) {
        return ~v & (Math.pow(2, digits) - 1);
    }
    console.log(flipbits(5, 3)); // outputs 2
    console.log(flipbits(2, 3)); // outputs 5
```

note - this isn't "arbitrary number of bits" ... it's 32 at best

> working with strings, you can have arbitrary bit length (this one wont work without transpiling in Internet Exploder)

```js
    var flipbits = str => str.split('').map(b => (1 - b).toString()).join('');

    console.log(flipbits('010')); // outputs 101
    console.log(flipbits('101')); // outputs 010
```

> The above in ES5

```js
    var flipbits = function flipbits(str) {
      return str.split('').map(function (b) {
        return (1 - b).toString();
      }).join('');
    };

    console.log(flipbits('010')); // outputs 101
    console.log(flipbits('101')); // outputs 010
```

Comment: Does that work for binary? Like I would be passing in a binary not decimal. It means 101 to 010( but not 10)

Comment: `Does that work for binary?` a **String** of 1's and 0's is not binary per se. All Numbers in javascript are binary, you can display them in binary, octal, decimal, hexadecimal, and all bases you can imagine ... but if you are working with strings of 1's and 0's (in a javascript String) then the second bit of code is what you want

Comment: When I put second bit of code, it gives me error. It doesn't look like a function. Should I include the first bit as well. I'm new to javacript

Comment: you're probably using internet explorer then - use the third snippet - it's ES5, which internet exploder almost understands

Comment: You don't need the *parseInt* in `1 - parseInt(b)`, the `-` operator will do the conversion to number. ;-)

Comment: `var flipbits = str => str.split('').map(b => (1 - b).toString()).join('');` a perfect function for fliping bits Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Inverting the bits will always be the same, but to convert an unsigned integer to a signed integer you can use the unsigned `>>>` shift operator to work on unsigned numbers:

```js
console.log(~5);     // -6
console.log(~5>>>0); // 4294967290
```

If you want to make sure you only flip the significant bits in the number, you'll instead want to mask it via an `&` operation with how many significant bits you need. Here is an example of the significant bit masking:

```js
function invert(x) {
  let significant = 0;
  let test = x;

  while (test > 1) {
    test = test >> 1;
    significant = (significant << 1) | 1;
  }

  return (~x) & significant;
}

console.log(invert(5));  // 2 (010 in binary)
```

Comment: this would work with "arbitrary-bit binary" up to 32 (or 31?) bits only ... arbitrary suggests any number of bits :p

Comment: using significant bits ... 010 -> 01, not 101 - the issue is that the question is too vague on how to determine the number of bits are significant

Comment: 5 = 101; so it's the 3 "significant" bits we're inverting (and we keep the rest at 0 as if they're not relevant to the original number).

Comment: He's not going from 2->5, only from 5->2.

Comment: `010 would be inverted to 101` - it's in the question

Comment: I think your solution doesn't work with number in binary form. I'm not passing in 5, but 101. 101 becomes 010

Comment: @ZacUwyoH oh, then just loop over the string characters and map 0->1 and 1->0...?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, ~ or tilde does this

> -(N+1)

So your current operation is **correct** but not what you are looking for:

```
~5
-(5 + 1)
-6
```

[Reference](https://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/great-mystery-of-the-tilde/)

Comment: But 5 is 101 -> 010 or 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function that converts numbers to binary as a string, flips the 0s and 1s, then converts back to a number. It seems to give the expected results, but looks pretty ugly:

```js
function flipBits(n) {
  return parseInt(n.toString(2).split('').map(bit => 1 - bit).join(''),2)
}

[0,1,2,3,4,5,123,987679876,987679875].forEach(
   n => console.log(n + ' -> ' + flipBits(n))
);
```

Maybe there's a mix of bitwise operators to do the same thing.

#### Edit

It seems you're working with strings, so just split, flip and join again:

```js
// Requires support for ECMAScript ed 5.1 for map and 
// ECMAScript 2015 for arrow functions
function flipStringBits(s) {
  return s.split('').map(c => 1 - c).join('');
}

['0','010','110','10011100110'].forEach(
  v => console.log(v + ' -> ' + flipStringBits(v))
);
```

Basic function for ECMAScript ed 3 (works everywhere, even IE 4).

```js
function flipStringBitsEd3(s) {
  var b = s.split('')
  for (var i = 0, iLen = b.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    b[i] = 1 - b[i];
  }
  return b.join('');
}

// Tests
console.log('Ed 3 version');
var data = ['0', '010', '110', '10011100110'];
for (var i = 0, iLen = data.length; i < iLen; i++) {
  console.log(data[i] + ' ->\n' + flipStringBitsEd3(data[i]) + '\n');
}
```

Works with any length string. The ed 3 version will work everywhere and is probably faster than functions using newer features.

Comment: warning, OP's environment doesn't support ES2015+ :p

Comment: @JaromandaX—ok, added ed 3 compliant code. Not tested in IE 4 but I expect it to work even there. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/(0)|(1)/`

```js
function toggle(n) {
  return n.replace(/(0)|(1)/g, function(m, p1, p2) { return p2 ? 0 : 1 });
}
    
console.log(
  toggle("10100"),
  toggle("101")  
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mask for number's width and take `xor` to flip the bits.

```js
/**
 * @param {number} num
 * @return {number}
 */
var findComplement = function(num) {
    let len = num.toString(2).length;
    let mask = Math.pow(2, len) - 1;
    return num ^ mask;
};
console.log(findComplement(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

For Integer values, you can use the javaScript program to reverse the order of the bits in a given integer and as a result return new integer as described below:

```
function binaryReverse(value) {
  return parseInt(value.toString(2).split('').reverse().join(''), 2);
}

console.log(binaryReverse(25));
console.log(binaryReverse(19));
```

Output:

```
 19
 25
```

Answer (score 0):

This takes a string of binary digits and returns the inverse. If the string has leading 0s they will also become 1s.

```
const inverseBin = bin => bin.replace(/0|1/g, bit => +!+bit);
```

Comment: Notice that `bit` is a string so you better do `=== "0"`. Btw you don't need to put capturing groups around the digits, `/0|1/g` would suffice.